# How to Get Version of an Executable file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, version, exe, resource-files

Salvete!  I am writing a vb.net program to update the readme files for my applications.  I want to extract the version number from other compiled applications.  I want to read the version number from the executable, not from its uncompiled resources.

How can I do this in vb.net without using an external tool like reshacker?

(I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890012/how-to-access-string-resource-from-another-application), but it is for another language.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a function like this to do it:

```
Private Function GetFileVersionInfo(ByVal filename As String) As Version
    Return Version.Parse(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filename).FileVersion)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Debug.WriteLine(GetFileVersionInfo("C:\foo\bar\myapp.exe").ToString)
```

Output:

```
4.2.9.281
```

Comment: Beautiful!  This is a perfect answer - with code, output, etc!  I spent about an hour of research trying to figure it out.  However, it doesn't work on every program, it seems - at least, I know it *does* only work on files with the file version given in the resource, but I tried it on one particular file that does show it, but this wouldn't capture it.  It seems to work on all my own programs though!